# how can i implement a meter just like analog sound meter?

Tags: iphone

I need to implement a meter just like sound meter for my iPhone app ,but I am little bit confuse about its implementation.
Please help how can I implement it?

Comment: What kind of sound meter?  What weighting or calibration?  What are you confused about?

Comment: I want to set a meter for use interaction. as user accelerates the mobile meter should show the intensity of motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code for the Android sound recorder's VU Meter](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/SoundRecorder/com/android/soundrecorder/VUMeter.java.htm) is available online and should get you started.

Comment: I want to set a meter for use interaction. as user accelerates the mobile meter should show the intensity of motion

Comment: What has that to do with the sound recorder then?

Answer (score 0):

You may use OpenGL based simple and easily extensible data visualization framework [gl-data-visualization-view](https://github.com/mike-dutka/gl-data-visualization-view)  to display UV meter. You should just add GLDataVisualizationView, set visualization type as VU meter and set value to visualize. There are also iPhone sample project which shows how to use framework.